# Static body bridging two other static bodies

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have two box2d bodies like below,
[image]

What I need is to create another body that kind of bridges this two bodies. I am not looking for a box2d joint, but a body that will be like a bridge touching the rightmost point of the first body and the leftmost point in the second body, like in this image (excuse my paint skills).
[image]

Problem is, looks like I am not getting the co-ordinates and angles on how to create the third (bridge) body. Here's my code below,

```
  Body body1, body2, bridge;

BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
bodyDef.position.set(350 / Constants.PIXELS_TO_METERS, 0 / Constants.PIXELS_TO_METERS);

body1 = world.createBody(bodyDef);

PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
shape.setAsBox(300 / Constants.PIXELS_TO_METERS, 300 / Constants.PIXELS_TO_METERS);

FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
fixtureDef.shape = shape;
fixtureDef.density = 1f;
body1.createFixture(fixtureDef);

BodyDef bodyDef2 = new BodyDef();
bodyDef2.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
bodyDef2.position.set(1600 / Constants.PIXELS_TO_METERS, 0 / Constants.PIXELS_TO_METERS);

body2 = world.createBody(bodyDef2);

PolygonShape shape2 = new PolygonShape();
shape2.setAsBox(300 / Constants.PIXELS_TO_METERS, 500 / Constants.PIXELS_TO_METERS);

FixtureDef fixtureDef2 = new FixtureDef();
fixtureDef2.shape = shape2;
fixtureDef2.density = 1f;
body2.createFixture(fixtureDef2);

BodyDef bodyDef3 = new BodyDef();
bodyDef3.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;

Vector2 a = new Vector2(body1.getPosition().x + 300 / Constants.PIXELS_TO_METERS, body1.getPosition().y + (300 + 50 / 2) / Constants.PIXELS_TO_METERS);
Vector2 b = new Vector2(body2.getPosition().x - 300 / Constants.PIXELS_TO_METERS, body2.getPosition().y + (300 + 50 / 2) / Constants.PIXELS_TO_METERS);


float distance = a.dst(b);
Vector2 bridgePos = new Vector2(a.x + distance / 2, a.y + 50 / 2 / Constants.PIXELS_TO_METERS);

bodyDef3.position.set(bridgePos);

float angle = (float) Math.atan2(a.y + 50 / Constants.PIXELS_TO_METERS, b.x);
bridge = world.createBody(bodyDef3);

PolygonShape shape3 = new PolygonShape();
shape3.setAsBox(distance / 2, 50 / Constants.PIXELS_TO_METERS);

FixtureDef fixtureDef3 = new FixtureDef();
fixtureDef3.shape = shape3;
fixtureDef3.density = 1f;
bridge.createFixture(fixtureDef3);
bridge.setTransform(bridgePos, angle);
```

This doesn't give the correct position or angle for the bridge, as it works for some body sizes and sometimes don't (yes, I have accounted for the hardcoded values for every change). I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to represent the definition of the first bodies as `Rectangle`s, then the problem of figuring out the position and rotation of the *bridges* goes aways as the bridge is always made up as a polygon touching the top corners of the `Rectangle`.

[image]

The above image was generated using this approach, full source code below. It uses `setAsBox` for the boxes, but uses an array of `Vector2`s to describe the polygon that is the bridge between boxes.

```
package com.bornander.androidstudiosandbox;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Shape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;

public class MyAndroidStudioSandboxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    World world;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    Box2DDebugRenderer renderer;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(24, 24);
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);

        world = new World(Vector2.Zero, true);

        renderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

        Body box1 = createBox(new Rectangle(-10, 0, 1, 4));
        Body box2 = createBox(new Rectangle(-8, 0, 1, 4));
        Body box3 = createBox(new Rectangle(-6, 1, 4, 2));
        Body box4 = createBox(new Rectangle(2, -1, 2, 2));
        Body box5 = createBox(new Rectangle(6, -3, 2, 2));

        buildBridge(box1, box2, 0.5f);
        buildBridge(box2, box3, 0.5f);
        buildBridge(box3, box4, 0.5f);
        buildBridge(box4, box5, 0.5f);
    }

    // This will only work for bodies where the userData has been set to a rectangle
    // describing the body
    private Body buildBridge(Body leftBox, Body rightBox, float thickness) {
        Rectangle lr = (Rectangle)leftBox.getUserData();
        Rectangle rr = (Rectangle)rightBox.getUserData();

        Vector2 v1 = new Vector2(lr.x + lr.width, lr.y + lr.height);
        Vector2 v2 = new Vector2(rr.x, rr.y + rr.height);
        Vector2 v3 = new Vector2(rr.x, rr.y + rr.height - thickness);
        Vector2 v4 = new Vector2(lr.x + lr.width, lr.y + lr.height - thickness);

        BodyDef nodeBodyDefinition = new BodyDef();
        nodeBodyDefinition.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;

        //nodeBodyDefinition.position.set(temp.x, temp.y);

        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        float density = 1.0f;
        shape.set(new Vector2[]{v1, v2, v3, v4});

        Body body = world.createBody(nodeBodyDefinition);
        final FixtureDef nodeFixtureDefinition = createFixtureDefinition(shape, density);

        body.createFixture(nodeFixtureDefinition);
        shape.dispose();

        return body;
    }

    private Body createBox(Rectangle rect) {
        Vector2 temp = new Vector2();
        BodyDef nodeBodyDefinition = new BodyDef();
        nodeBodyDefinition.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;

        rect.getCenter(temp);
        nodeBodyDefinition.position.set(temp.x, temp.y);

        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        float density = 1.0f;
        shape.setAsBox(rect.getWidth() / 2.0f, rect.getHeight() / 2.0f);

        Body body = world.createBody(nodeBodyDefinition);
        body.setUserData(rect);
        body.setTransform(temp.x, temp.y, 0);
        final FixtureDef nodeFixtureDefinition = createFixtureDefinition(shape, density);

        body.createFixture(nodeFixtureDefinition);
        shape.dispose();

        return body;
    }

    private static FixtureDef createFixtureDefinition(final Shape shape, final float density) {
        final FixtureDef nodeFixtureDefinition = new FixtureDef();
        nodeFixtureDefinition.shape = shape;
        nodeFixtureDefinition.friction = 1;
        nodeFixtureDefinition.density = density;
        nodeFixtureDefinition.restitution = 0.1f;
        return nodeFixtureDefinition;
    }



    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        world.step(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 4, 4);
        camera.update();

        renderer.render(world, camera.combined);
    }
}
```